# Maven - No plugin found for prefix 'tomcat7' in the current project

Tags: java, maven

I've created a Maven project with the archetype "webapp" but when I start the command "mvn tomcat7:start", I've the following error :

```
No plugin found for prefix 'tomcat7' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\dark\.m2\repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

My project structure :

```
-src 
   -main
       -resources
       -webapp
          -WEB-INF
             -web.xml
          -index.jsp
-target
    -classes
    -dependency
        - // the 'dependency' directory contains all the jar files
    -lbagno
    -maven-archiver
    -surefire
    lbagno.war
```

My pom.xml contains well the dependency for tomcat.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.myspace</groupId>
 <artifactId>lbagno</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>lbagno Maven Webapp</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


 <dependencies>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>3.8.1</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
         <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.2</version>
         <type>maven-plugin</type>
     </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
    <finalName>lbagno</finalName>
 </build>

</project>
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Do you have any solutions ?

Thank you

Answer (score 9):

I know it was asked a year ago, but my answer might work for somebody other than me.

If creating the build tag in the `pom.xml` file not works, try editing the `settings.xml` file at your .m2 directory this way:

```
<pluginGroups>
  ...
  <pluginGroup>org.apache.tomcat.maven</pluginGroup>
  ...
</pluginGroups>
```

I found the solution here:
http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/

Comment: I had been deploying my Maven project to Tomcat with a `pom.xml` (like @RC) declaration for months without a problem, but suddenly, with no apparent change, it broke. Your solution got it deploying again.

Comment: why is this a special case to add it to the settings.xml?

Comment: This solved the issue for me. This is the right answer

Answer (score 2):

First, there is no start goal, see the [goals page](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) of the doc.

Next, it's a plugin, you declared it as a dependency, this is why you get this error, I suggest you read the [usage page](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html) of the plugin.

Here is a schematic structure of the `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
    <!-- ... -->

    <dependencies>
        <!-- your deps here -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- your default build plugins here -->
        </plugins>
    <build>

    <!-- ... -->
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
mvn clean install tomcat7:run
```

Answer (score 1):

Run mvn with `-X -e` params. This should give you more information about the error.

I saw that you don't have any `pluginRepositories` declared. Add the following lines to your pom.xml:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>apache.snapshots</id>
        <name>Apache Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete this part from your dependency and put this line of code in plugins on your projects pom.xml.
From dependency delete this line of codes:

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
     <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.2</version>
     <type>maven-plugin</type>
 </dependency>
```

and put this in ....

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</plugin>
```

This will surely work.