# I can't run java spring mvc project with maven on local host

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I'm trying to run my project, but I get this error:

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (13 KB at 15.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 KB at 21.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.880 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-16T10:13:55+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/153M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'org.apache.tomcat.maven' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\LA\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

I saw this answer to my error:

```
This is most likely because your maven is setup not to look for unknown plugin directly from central, eg: you have an internal company maven repository proxy. Have a look at your ~/.m2/repository and check if your maven is using any mirror, and ensure tomcat7 plugin is available on the mirror / use another mirror. Stack overflow has a lost of question posted about this problem
```

but I don't know how to see the maven plagin, 
someone can explain to me where can I see the maven plugin? and how to compere it to the tomcat7 plugin?

this is the pom.xml:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.gerrytan.pizzashop</groupId>
  <artifactId>pizzashop</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.2.2.Final</hibernate.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Java EE -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Others -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

after I debug the project I also get this line:
     Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/)]

what does it mean?

thank you!

Comment: this may be solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073123/maven-no-plugin-found-for-prefix-tomcat7-in-the-current-project

Comment: I added the pom.xml please  get look on this,